# HttpWebRequest not passing Credentials simple form authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, form-authentication

My code is like this

```
Doc doc = new Doc();
string url =  HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
// required for HttpWebResponse.Cookies
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); 

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if (response.Cookies.Count>0) { // includes ASP.NET_SessionId
    bool needsCookie2 = false;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Cookie: ");
    for(int i = 0; i<response.Cookies.Count; ++i) {
        Cookie cookie = response.Cookies[i];
        if(!needsCookie2 && cookie.Version!=1)
             needsCookie2 = true;
        if(i>0)
             builder.Append("; ");
        builder.Append(cookie.ToString());
    }
    builder.Append(!needsCookie2? "\r\n": "\r\nCookie2: $Version=1\r\n");
    doc.HtmlOptions.HttpAdditionalHeaders = builder.ToString();
}

doc.HtmlOptions.NoCookie = true;
doc.HtmlOptions.HostWebBrowser = false;

// cookieless Forms Authentication adds authentication ticket to the URL
int id = doc.AddImageUrl(response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri);
doc.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/media/pdf/1212.pdf"));
doc.Clear();
```

I am using **simple form authentication** in my website and I need to authenticate this        webRequest in order to print a pdf through abcPDF, as my login details are stored in cookie i am trying to get it from there and add to my request. I assume the error is in line `request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say the website is using *forms authentication*, but your request is using *basic authentication* credentials:

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

You'll need to either switch the website to basic authentication, or perform a POST request against your login page to get the session cookie/token to use in subsequent requests.

Comment: can you give me a code sample for POST request against login page and how i need to integrate it with my code?